# Calling SOAP Web Service Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, xamarin.forms

I'm new to xamarin.forms and am attempting to call a web service. For example I have been using http://bernera.zapto.org/astronomy/astronomy.asmx . I understand how to add the web reference to the project itself but I'm unclear of the next steps to actually call one of those methods. I've looked online at tutorials and they aren't painting a clear picture. Please help me understand how to use a web service function after adding the web reference.

Comment: Try to implement one, and comeback here to ask if you get stuck with your attempted implementation : [Consuming ASMX](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/asmx/)

Comment: I figured out how to do it by adding a web reference to the android specific project in Visual Studio. What I can't seem to figure out is how to add the web reference to the shared xamarin.forms project. There is no "add web reference" option. I tried to research it and can't find anything specific to xamarin.forms.